# More epochs or more layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

What is the difference in training if one uses more epochs or more layers?

Should these train equally, assuming consistent hyperparams?

```
for epoch in range(20):
    LSTM
```

and

```
for epoch in range(5):
    LSTM -> LSTM -> LSTM -> LSTM
```

I understand that there would be a difference after training.  In the first case, you would send any test batch through one trained LSTM cell, while in the 2nd case, it would go through 4 trained cells.  My question pertains to training.

Seems they should be identical.

Comment: Why should they be identical?

Comment: Is it that in case 1, the output state doesn't get passed to the next epoch, where in case 2 the output state passes 3 times?  The output states should get passed in both cases

Comment: Yes. Also the first layer always receives the raw input, while the deeper layers receive the hidden state of previous LSTM cells

Comment: Bingo.  That is what I needed to see.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you make a big confusion between very different concepts. Let's us go back to the basics. Very simply, in a supervised machine learning experiment you have some training data X, and a model. A model is like a function with internal parameters, you give it some data and it gives you back a prediction. Here, let us say our model has one layer, which is an LSTM. That means the parameters of our model are the parameters of the LSTM (I won't go into what they are, if you don't know them you should read the paper introducing LSTMs).

What is an epoch: very roughly, "training for n epochs" means looping n times on the training data. You show each example n times to the model for update. The more epochs the more you get your network acustomed to your training data. (I'm being very overly simplistic).

I hope it is clearer now that epochs and layers are in no way related to the layers. The layers are what your model is made of, and the epochs is about how many times you will show your examples to the model.

If you put 5 LSTM layers, you will just have 5 times more parameters. But in any case, each of your training examples will go through the 1 or 5 stacked LSTM layers...